# T-SQL - Using CASE with Parameters in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, case

I'm running a report on a `Sales` table:

`SaleId INT | SalesUserID INT | SiteID INT | BrandId INT| SaleDate DATETIME`

I'm having a nightmare trying to do something like this with a set of Nullable parameters `@SalesUserID`, `@SiteId`, `@BrandID` and two DateTime params.

Additional Point: Only ONE of the filter parameters will ever be passed as a Non-Null value.

```
SELECT * from Sales
WHERE
     SaleDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

AND
    SalesUserID IN
(
    Select SalesUserID FROM Sales
    WHERE
        SaleDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

    AND

        CASE
            WHEN @SalesUserId IS NOT NULL THEN SalesUserId = @SalesUserID
            WHEN @SiteId Is Not Null THEN SiteId = @SiteId
            ELSE BrandId = @BrandID
        END

)
```

My use of `CASE` here smells bad but I'm not sure how to correct it. Can you please assist?

Thanks.

5arx

Comment: You need to be real clear on what you want here (and test it well). I'm thinking you want sales for this SalesUser if I ask for SalesUser, OR sales for this Site if I ask for Site, or brand. But not that you may want sales for this SalesUser only at this Site. Big difference.

Comment: I'm still struggling with pinning down the business requirements - the issues are that SalesUsers are based at multiple sites and sites can host multiple brands...

But if I pass @SalesUserId then I want all his/her sales regardless of site or brand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you want a CASE statement at all, but a compound conditional... Give this a shot and let me know:

```
select * 
from Sales
where SaleDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and
   (
    (@SalesUserId is not null and SalesUserId = @SalesUserID)
    or (@SiteId is not null and SiteId = @SiteId)
    or (BrandId = @BrandID)
   )
```

Comment: Looks OK to me (but, as this question suggests, I'm no expert). Thanks v. much.

Am I right in thinking this cannot be expressed using CASE ...?

Comment: @5arx right, as far as I know you would not ever use CASE for something like that.  This is far simpler don't you think?

Comment: Isn't it possible for this to get a different result? In the CASE, only one of the three conditions will be applied. But in your version, more than one can be true. Couldn't you get all matches for @SalesUserId AND @SiteID?

Comment: I can see that it would be finer-grained if you used AND, but with OR, you would get results for one SalesUser and a different Site where that SalesUser doesn't work, and a Brand that they don't sell. In the end, all of this SQL is correct, but not all of it is doing what the questioner wants. It's a tricky situation.

Comment: @DOK Good point.. definitely up to interpretation by the OP.  I was mistaken in a comment or two and removed them for clarity.

Comment: @Fosco - Its much simpler (and under usual circumstances would have been my approach but I had an idea CASE would be more ... elegant or something)

Have edited the question to hopefully make myself clearer.
I'm not sure I understand why this would allow me to pass more than one of the filter params given they are OR'd rather than AND'd. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @5arx I was mistaken about that as pointed out by DOK.  A brain burp, if you will.  CASE only belongs in the SELECT clause, in my humble opinion, as far as elegance goes.

Comment: @Fosco - This was a tremendous help! I am currently writing a query for a search. Using CASE in my WHERE clause was giving me error after error. This is far more simple, elegant, and actually works for the 7 search variables I have to evaluate.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood you correctly, you want the three conditions either be NULL or checked for:

```
WHERE
    /* ... */
    AND SalesUserId = ISNULL(@SalesUserId, SalesUserId)
    AND SiteId      = ISNULL(@SiteId, SiteId)
    AND BrandId     = ISNULL(@BrandID, BrandID)
```

Be aware that this forces a table scan which might not be in your best interest.

Comment: @Quick: It's hard to avoid anyway in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

This should work and use any index if you want to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT * 
from Sales 
WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
AND SalesUserID = CASE WHEN @SalesUserID IS NULL THEN 
SalesUserID ELSE @SalesUserID END
```

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE()` returns the 1st non NULL argument so you could;

```
...
WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  AND SalesUserId = COALESCE(@SalesUserId, SalesUserId)
  AND SiteId = COALESCE(@SiteId, SiteId)
  AND BrandID = COALESCE(@BrandID, BrandId)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dynamic generated code in such a circumstance:

```
declare @SalesUserId int,@SiteId int,@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime,@BrandID int
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    set @sql = N'
    SELECT * from Sales
    WHERE
         SaleDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

    AND
        SalesUserID IN
    (
        Select SalesUserID FROM Sales
        WHERE
            SaleDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
    ' +
            CASE
                WHEN @SalesUserId IS NOT NULL THEN 'SalesUserId = @SalesUserID'
                WHEN @SiteId Is Not Null THEN 'SiteId = @SiteId'
                ELSE 'BrandId = @BrandID'
            END

    +')'

    print @sql

    exec sp_executesql @sql
        , N'@SalesUserId int,
            @SiteId int,
            @StartDate datetime,
            @EndDate datetime,
            @BrandID int'
            ,@SalesUserId
            ,@SiteId
            ,@StartDate
            ,@EndDate
            ,@BrandID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a job for dynamic SQl if you want performance.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: +1 agreed. Either this or several stored procedures that handle one case each (and possibly are wrapped in a single SP to abstract them away). This is not the most useful approach if there are many varying search criteria, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
from Sales 
WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
AND SalesUserID = CASE WHEN @SalesUserID IS NULL THEN 
SalesUserID ELSE @SalesUserID END
```